# How to add Sql\Expression in front of column Name in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

How to get Sql like this :

```
select * from foo where LOWER(foo_name) = 'test';
```

what i get is if Sql\Expression in right, not in left.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can user code snippet like that.

```
$where = new Where();
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$where->addPredicate(new Predicate\Expression('LOWER(foo_name) = ?', 'test' ));
$select->from('foo')->where($where);
```

However I dont think Sql\Expression on right side is possible on Zend Framework 2.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks :) It is really hard to find any documentation about that!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
$sql = new SQL($adaptor);
$select = $sql->select()->from(array('f'=>'foo'));
$select = $select->where('foo_name' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("LOWER('test')"));
```

Above query would return as:

```
SELECT `f`.* FROM `foo` AS `f` WHERE `foo_name` = LOWER('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

For others out looking for similar, there are actually quite a few different ways to achieve this as of ZF 2.2

**Chaining (same as the accepted answer)**

```
<?php
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from( array( 'f' => 'foo' ) )
->where
->addPredicate( new Predicate\Expression( 'LOWER(f.foo_name) = ?', 'test' ) );

//SELECT `f`.* FROM `foo` AS `f` WHERE LOWER(f.foo_name) = :where1
//:where1 = 'test'
?>
```

Note the absence of the execution command "()" of Select::$where allowing you to continue the method chaining.
Select::$where has a  __get Magic method catch which returns the protected Select::$_where property within the Select object which is an instance of Sql\Where.

**Predicate\Literal 1**

```
<?php
$select->where( "LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'" );

//SELECT `f`.* FROM `foo` AS `f` WHERE LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'
?>
```

**Predicate\Literal 2**

```
<?php
$select->where( array( "LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'" ) );

//SELECT `f`.* FROM `foo` AS `f` WHERE LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'
?>
```

The two above automatically create a Predicate\Literal object for you if the indexed value (column identifier) of the array or argument supplied to the Select::where method is a string.

**Predicate\Expression (manual)**

```
<?php
$select->where( new Predicate\Expression( "LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'" ) );

//SELECT `f`.* FROM `foo` AS `f` WHERE LOWER(f.foo_name) = 'test'
?>
```