# ZF2 Zend\Db\Sql aggregate function as key in WHERE

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, aggregate-functions

i found some solutions for Zend\Db\Sql SQL aggregate functions, but they are not working for me :(

my old PDO Statement (works with "simple" PDO):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e') FROM termine WHERE MONTH(date) = ?
```

Solution for the first aggregate function:

```
$select->columns(array(new Expression("DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e')")));
```

But for second aggregate function i have no idea and cant find anything.

```
$select->where(array('MONTH(date)' => $month));
```

...is no solution, because it throws an error.

I know: one more table column (month) can be my solution ...but it is not good enough.

How can i use SQL aggregate functions as key in Zend\Db\Sql\Select()->where()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Sql\Expression in front of column Name in ZF2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190872/how-to-add-sql-expression-in-front-of-column-name-in-zf2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how good of an answer this is because I have not tested it. However, one of the Predicate classes is [Expression](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Predicate/Expression.php). Which, I believe, should do what you're looking for. Then you can just pass the Predicate to the where method (it takes arrays, PredicateSets, Predicates, and Where classes).

There's also the possibility of making Month() a column and using the having clause. For example:

```
$select->columns(array(
     new Expression("DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e')"),
     'month' => new Expression("MONTH(date)"),
  )
)->having(array('month' => $month));
```

This I know works because I'm using it on a couple of queries. However, using the Expression prediate might be the better way to do it.